# Referring to resource for Shape Drawable stroke width

Tags: android, android-layout

Eclipse is able to render my layout when it includes:

```
...
<shape>
...
<stroke>
...
android:width="@strings/someWidth"
```

where someWidth is defined in strings.xml as

```
<string name="someWidth">5dp</string>
```

but it crashes on a real device, and only works if I use a direct string, like:

```
android:width="5dp"
```

How can I use a resource for the stroke width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [dimension resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Create a `dimens.xml` file inside your values folder with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="some_width">5dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You can refer to this using `@dimen/some_width`.

Comment: uggh, you are correct, I should have seen that.  Sorry, newbie.